# VBA Upload chinese characters to sql server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have some problem uploading chinese characters from excel file to SQL server database. I end up with ???? instead of chinese marks.

What i do in code is

`Dim ProjectList As Variant`
`ProjectList = Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(LastRow, "AX")).Value`

And then i use this array in parameters

`Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ProjectList(i, 7)))`

How can i upload chinese characters instead of ???? to database?

Comment: in your table schema is the column defined as varchar? `nvarchar` supports unicode. Change the column's datatype and you are good.

Comment: Also, change the parameter type to adNVarChar.

Comment: SQL Server and VBA can handle Unicode just fine, provided you *do* use Unicode, ie `nvarchar` fields and `adNVarChar` parameters. You used ASCII instead (`adVarChar`), which resulted in conversion errors. Any character that couldn't be converted to ASCII was replaced by `?`

Comment: Columns in tables are nvarchar but when i try to use `adNVarChar` it says "variable not defined" 
I used `adVarWChar` instead and it looks good now in DB. 
Is `adVarWChar` ok to use?